# PDF File Downloads on Desktop Web browsers but not on mobile web browsers

Tags: javascript, json, download, fetch-api

My JavaScript code is below. It is used to download a PDF which is returned as a data url from the server.

```
fetch('/Documents/GenerateReportPdf',
{
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData,
})
.then(response => {
     return response.json();
})
.then(data => {

     const fileName = `Report.pdf`;
     const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
     downloadLink.href = data.url;
     downloadLink.download = fileName;
     downloadLink.click();
})
.catch(err => {
     console.error(err);
});
```

The response JSON is like this:

```
url: "data:application/pdf;base64,......."
```

This code works on desktop web browsers and the file is downloaded successfully, but no file gets downloaded on mobile devices and I also do not get any errors.

Comment: which "mobile devices" running which browsers

Comment: Safari - iPhoneXR,
Chrome - Android

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between desktop browser and mobile is click and touch. In mobile, they work normally but you simulated "click" action using "download.click()". Sometime it doesn't work because onClick and onTouch is diffrent. Maybe mobile regard click() is not appropriate. How about making "a" on screen and let user click it or using route?